# Start Activity from NavigationDrawer's menu doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have this navigation drawer built with placeholder view, however when I press logout button it doesn't start the activity I'd like to start after logout. 
Here is the code, could someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Thanks

```
@Layout(R.layout.drawer_item)
public class DrawerMenuItem {

    public static final int DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT = 8;

    private int mMenuPosition;
    private Context mContext;
    private DrawerCallBack mCallBack;

    public DrawerMenuItem(Context context, int menuPosition) {
        mContext = context;
        mMenuPosition = menuPosition;
    }

    @Resolve
    private void onResolved() {
        switch (mMenuPosition){

            case DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
                itemIcon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp));
                itemNameTxt.setText("Logout");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Click(R.id.mainView)
    private void onMenuItemClick(){
        switch (mMenuPosition){

            case DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(mCallBack != null)mCallBack.onLogoutMenuSelected();
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext,MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setDrawerCallBack(DrawerCallBack callBack) {
        mCallBack = callBack;
    }

    public interface DrawerCallBack{
        void onLogoutMenuSelected();
    }
}
```

Here's my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.albej.orederveg">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddFood"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:name=".OpenOrders" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FarmerMenuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ItemListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SingleFoodActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SingleOrderActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainTabActivity"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And here my main activity that I'd like to start on logout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email,pass,loc,name;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);

        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Farmers");

    }
    //Signing up
    public  void signupButtonClicked(View view){
        final String email_text=email.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass_text=pass.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_text)){
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_text,pass_text).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user = mDatabase.child(user_id);

                        current_user.child("email").setValue(email_text)

                        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(detailsIntent);

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void signinButtonClicked(View view){
        Intent loginIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
}
```

Below the Logcat

```
01-27 18:15:37.953 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-27 18:15:52.743 10376-10574/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.example.albej.orederveg/cache/picasso-cache/journal.tmp
01-27 18:16:37.193 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-27 18:16:37.293 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at com.mindorks.placeholderview.ViewBinder$1.onClick(ViewBinder.java:159)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err: Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:734)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:721)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:345)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:     at com.example.albej.orederveg.DrawerMenuItem.onMenuItemClick(DrawerMenuItem.java:120)
01-27 18:16:37.313 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/System.err:    ... 11 more
01-27 18:16:37.323 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
01-27 18:16:37.323 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{fd99f00 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203a7 android:id/toast_layout_root}
01-27 18:16:37.373 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
01-27 18:16:37.393 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
01-27 18:16:39.333 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
01-27 18:17:39.763 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 107315
01-27 18:17:39.773 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Using measurement service
01-27 18:17:39.773 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-27 18:17:39.783 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Activity paused, time: 181999657
01-27 18:17:39.793 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=107315, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainTabActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=6299809065178216245}]
01-27 18:17:39.803 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Using measurement service
01-27 18:17:39.803 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-27 18:17:39.863 10376-10376/com.example.albej.orederveg V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3b9ab2c token=android.os.BinderProxy@fc50a4f {com.example.albej.orederveg/com.example.albej.orederveg.MainTabActivity}} show : true
01-27 18:17:39.863 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-27 18:17:39.863 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
01-27 18:17:44.913 10376-10634/com.example.albej.orederveg V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-27 18:20:51.153 10376-10428/com.example.albej.orederveg W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: Oh man, I see so many weird stuff in this code that I don't know where to start. What is this part doing: `MainTabActivity maintab=new MainTabActivity(); maintab.Logout();`? Is this `MainTabActivity` real Activity? If yes, please read a bit more about activities. You should never call `new Activity()`!

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your reply, you're right, but I tried at the beginning  `mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext,MainActivity.class));`, but it didn't work.. so I was trying anything that might work. The rest of the drawer works fine though. Do you have any idea how could I call a new activity when logout is pressed? or where I could read about? Before I was using a simple button and it was working fine..

Comment: [The Official Android Documentaiton](https://developer.android.com/) shows [how to start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing

```
MainTabActivity maintab=new MainTabActivity();
maintab.Logout();
```

with

```
SaveSharedPreference.clearUserName(mContext);
mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext, MainActivity.class));
```

should solve the issue. If you prefere to have this part of the code in sepparate method, you should keep that method in `DrawerMenuItem`.
If it's still not working please check is there anything in Logcat when you click on the button and also add code from `AndroidManifest.xml` and `MainActivity.java`to your question.

**Update:**

Problem is pretty clear from this line from LogCat log:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

This means that the `mContext` is not Activity's context.
To fix this make sure that when creating `DrawerMenuItem` you use Activity's context. In the line where you have something like this: `new DrawerMenuItem(context, menuPosition)`, `context` needs to be Activity.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your answer. I've already tried `mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext, MainActivity.class));` but it doesn't start the activity (the Toast message though is displayed). I've uploaded the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Is `Toast.makeText(mContext, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` being shown?

Comment: Not sure how experienced you are with debugger. Can you check if onCreate in new Activity is being called. If you don't know how to use debugger, add Toast there.

Comment: I've tried with the debugger and the problem is indeed that the activity is not called at all

Comment: I've tried with `((MainTabActivity) mContext).finish();` but doesn't do anything either. It seems it doesn't finish the activity MainTabActivity. Why it behaves so strangely?

Comment: Can you add log to your question? What is there in the log when you press button?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for suggesting to look at the Logcat, it seems that there are some error, I'm not really sure how to interpret them though. `W/System.err:     at com.example.albej.orederveg.DrawerMenuItem.onMenuItemClick(DrawerMenuItem.java:121)` Corresponds to the line `mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext,MainActivity.class));`

Comment: There should be more lines related to this error in LogCat. Can you add them also?

Comment: I've added all the lines where an err is mentioned. Is this enough?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Vladimir thanks a lot for your time, your answer it solved my problem!

Comment: It was enough to change `.addView(new DrawerMenuItem(this.getApplicationContext(), DrawerMenuItem.DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT));` into `.addView(new DrawerMenuItem(this, DrawerMenuItem.DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT));`

Comment: Yes. That's basically it. Replacing Application's context with Activity's context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:-

```
case DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mCallBack != null)mCallBack.onLogoutMenuSelected();
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent (mContext,MainActivity.class));
        break;
```

Write this:-

```
case DRAWER_MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mCallBack != null)mCallBack.onLogoutMenuSelected();
        break;
```